# how to make one form field compulsory to select or fill in other in django model form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, modelform

i am creating where a one form field is dependent on other means only when one form is filled then only he can select or fill the other form field of the same model in django

```
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField
class student(models.Model):
    lunch_choice = [ 
        ('Sandwich', 'Sandwich'),
        ('Salad', 'Salad'),
        ('omlete', 'omlete'),
    ]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False)
    classs =  models.CharField(max_length70, blank=True)
    lunch =  MultiSelectField(choices=lunch_choice, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

i am using this model as form what i want if user want to submit the form and want select choices from lunch he has to fill the class field otherwise he will not be allowed to submit the form or he has to leave both the field then submit the form
any ideas and suggestion will be appreciated
i want the class field must be filed to select from lunch multiselect field

Comment: If you want to do client side validation you have to use [tag:javascript]

Comment: @Blackranger updated the code, made a version of the model with MultiSelectField.

Comment: @Blackranger added a code with a variant of the form class, in which, if you send an empty class field, then the rest of the fields become inactive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did it without using MultiSelectField, because I don't know how to do it with it. Used the "clean" example taken from [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/validation/#validating-fields-with-clean)
If 'classs' is not filled in at the time of submitting, a ValidationError will be fired with output to the screen and the form will not submit. Also added a 'lunch' check for an empty value.
You can uncomment the triple quotes in 'def clean' and see how it works without it.

By code: the 'student' model is created. Based on it, the class MyForm is created in the forms.py file. The template(tam_form.html) and the form class are passed to the view class(MyFormCreateView).

**My application is called bboard, so the template path looks like this: template_name = 'bboard/tam_form.html' you must replace 'bboard' with your own.**

success_url = reverse_lazy('adding') where we return the result, in this case in the same form.

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import *

urlpatterns = [
    path('adding/', MyFormCreateView.as_view(), name='adding'),
]
```

templates(tam_form.html)

```
<h2>form</h2>
<form method="post">
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{ form.as_p }}
      <input type="submit" value="adding">
</form>
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class student(models.Model):
    lunch_choice = [
        ('Sandwich', 'Sandwich'),
        ('Salad', 'Salad'),
        ('omlete', 'omlete'),
    ]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False)
    classs =  models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True)
    lunch =  models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=lunch_choice, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from .models import student
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class MyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = student
        fields = ('name', 'classs', 'lunch')

    #"""
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        classs = cleaned_data.get("classs")
        lunch = cleaned_data.get("lunch")

        if classs:
            print('classs field is filled')
        else:
            raise ValidationError(
                    "fill in the field classs"
                )
        if lunch == '':
            raise ValidationError(
                "fill in lunch"
            )
    #"""
```

views.py

```
from django.views.generic.edit import CreateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .forms import MyForm

class MyFormCreateView(CreateView):
    template_name = 'bboard/tam_form.html'
    form_class = MyForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('adding')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

**Update 09/15/2022.** if you need it with MultiSelectField, then I did this by changing the model, the rest remains unchanged:

```
class student(models.Model):
    lunch_choice = [
        ('Sandwich', 'Sandwich'),
        ('Salad', 'Salad'),
        ('omlete', 'omlete'),
    ]
    name = models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=False)
    classs =  models.CharField(max_length=70, blank=True)
    lunch = MultiSelectField(choices=lunch_choice, null=True, blank=True, max_choices=3, max_length=30)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

**Update 09/16/2022.**

Fixed the 'def clean' function, if the 'lunch' field is not empty, the length is greater than 0 and it does not equal an empty string, and 'classs' is an empty string, a ValidationError is raised with a 'fill in classes' page output. The form is not submitted when the button is clicked. If the 'classes' field is filled in and clicked submit, the data is written to the database. You can see it in the gif I attached.

Also added another option, if the 'classs' field is not filled, then when the button is pressed, the remaining fields become inactive. If you fill in the 'classs' field and click the button, the fields will be unlocked. This option is commented out.

```
from django.forms import ModelForm
from django import forms
from .models import student
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

class MyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = student
        fields = ('name', 'classs', 'lunch')

    
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        classs = cleaned_data.get("classs")
        lunch = cleaned_data.get("lunch")

        if len(lunch) > 0 and lunch!= '' and classs == '':
            raise ValidationError(
                "fill in classs"
            )
    

    """
    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        classs = cleaned_data.get("classs")
        lunch = cleaned_data.get("lunch")

        if classs:
            self.fields['lunch'].widget.attrs.update({'enabled': 'enabled'})
            self.fields['name'].widget.attrs.update({'enabled': 'enabled'})
        if len(lunch) > 0 and classs == '':
            self.fields['lunch'].widget.attrs.update({'disabled': 'disabled'})
            self.fields['name'].widget.attrs.update({'disabled': 'disabled'})
            raise ValidationError(
                "fill in the field classs"
            )
    """
```

[image]

Comment: didn't work i tried that it just got saved without showing any error

Comment: I want the form not to be submitted and data should not be stored in the model if user is selecting lunch without filling the class data  in every case the form should get saved like if user is fill only name it has to be stored if user fill name and class it should also be submitted if and only user is select some option from lunch it has to throw him error that user must fill class field to use that or save that form I already in my name field made blank=false

Comment: you say it didn't work. I checked in the admin panel, it worked for me. The data is not stored in the database until the classs field is filled. I'll try to do it tomorrow with gifs to show visually. Have you tried the option that is before the update?

Comment: Are save and send the same thing? Do you mean by this save in the database?
Do I understand you correctly:
1. We select lunch without filling in the class data (do not save), we create an error.
2. Filled in the name and class, did not choose lunch, save.
3. Filled in  name,  class was not filled in, save.         4. we choose lunch, the class is filled in, the name is not filled in, what are we doing?

Comment: yes you get me the name does have to do with any of it so by keeping that field aside I only want to show an error if user select multiselectfield without filling class throw him error snd ask him to fill the class field in order to proceed

Comment: i can do it with javascript but I want to use Django

Comment: @Blackranger updated, look at the code for today's date.

Comment: appreciated it worked now

Comment: can u help with this too https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73717878/based-on-model-multiselectfield-show-result-in-template-django please